# How can I make the following picture as a network in R (qgraph or igraph)?

Tags: r, networking, igraph, r-qgraph

I would like to make the following picture in R. I draw it but i would like to weight the edge size according to their value, use this two different colors (red and blue), and two different edge types (dashed and not dashed). How do I do this?

[network drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM05y.png)

Here is the code for the dataframe

```
data.frame(Node = c("MF", "MF", "SF","SF", "AFS","AFS"), Edge.col= c(rep(c("Blue","Red"),3)), RC = c(215, 79, 38, 22, 659, 43), SER = c(285, 43, 120, 44, 252, 95))
```

Comment: edit your question with data that you're using to build the graph. use this for posting questions on SO: [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok. Now I added the data.frame function with the dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make the picture. I couldn't do in R, but I used the software graphviz. Below I show the code:

```
digraph g {
layout = "neato"

MF -> SER [color=blue, penwidth=3.24, label = "285"];
MF -> SER [color=red, penwidth=0.49, label = "43"];
MF -> RC [style=dashed, color=blue, penwidth=2.44, label = "215"];
MF -> RC [style=dashed, color=red, penwidth=0.9, label = "79"];
SF -> SER [color=blue, penwidth=1.36, label = "120"];
SF -> SER [color=red, penwidth=0.5, label = "44"];
SF -> RC [style=dashed, color=blue, penwidth=0.43, label = "38"];
SF -> RC [style=dashed, color=red, penwidth=0.25, label = "22"];
AFS -> SER [color=blue, penwidth=2.86, label = "252"];
AFS -> SER [color=red, penwidth=1.08, label = "95"];
AFS -> RC [style=dashed, color=blue, penwidth=7.5, label = "659"];
AFS -> RC [style=dashed, color=red, penwidth=0.49, label = "43"];

MF[pos="0,2!", height = 1, width = 1.5, fontsize = 28, fontname = "Helvetica"]
SF [pos="-2,-2!", height = 1, width = 1.5, fontsize = 28, fontname = "Helvetica"]
AFS [pos="2,-2!", height = 1, width = 1.5, fontsize = 28, fontname = "Helvetica"]
RC [pos="1,0!", label = "BB",shape=Mdiamond, height = 1, width = 1.5, fontsize = 28, fontname = "Helvetica"];
SER [pos="-1,0!", label = "P-S", shape=Msquare, height = 1, width = 1, fontsize = 28, fontname = "Helvetica"];
}
```